# vtkCellLocator: FindClosestPoint usage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vtk

The definition of the "FindClosestPoint" function is the following:

```
   def FindClosestPoint(self, p_float=None, p_float=None_1, p_float=None_2, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown; NOTE: unreliably restored from __doc__ 
    """
    V.FindClosestPoint([float, float, float], [float, float, float],
        vtkGenericCell, int, int, float)
    C++: void FindClosestPoint(double x[3], double closestPoint[3],
        vtkGenericCell *cell, vtkIdType &cellId, int &subId,
        double &dist2) override;
    V.FindClosestPoint([float, float, float], [float, float, float],
        int, int, float)
    C++: virtual void FindClosestPoint(double x[3],
        double closestPoint[3], vtkIdType &cellId, int &subId,
        double &dist2)

    Return the closest point and the cell which is closest to the
    point x. The closest point is somewhere on a cell, it need not be
    one of the vertices of the cell.  This version takes in a
    vtkGenericCell to avoid allocating and deallocating the cell. 
    This is much faster than the version which does not take a *cell,
    especially when this function is called many times in a row such
    as by a for loop, where the allocation and deallocation can be
    done only once outside the for loop.  If a cell is found, "cell"
    contains the points and ptIds for the cell "cellId" upon exit.
    """
    pass
```

In my code I use the function like this:

```
my_cell_locator = vtk.vtkCellLocator()
my_cell_locator.SetDataSet(reverse.GetOutput()) # reverse.GetOutput() --> vtkPolyData
cellId = 0
c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
subId = 0
d = 0.0
my_cell_locator.FindClosestPoint([-23.7, -48.4, -1096.4], c, cellId, subId, d)
```

And this leads to the following error:

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I don't know how to use this function correctly. What is wrong?
What would be the correct usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to change the code to the following:

```
reverse.Update()
my_cell_locator = vtk.vtkCellLocator()
my_cell_locator.SetDataSet(reverse.GetOutput())  # reverse.GetOutput() --> vtkPolyData
my_cell_locator.BuildLocator()

cellId = vtk.reference(0)
c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
subId = vtk.reference(0)
d = vtk.reference(0.0)
my_cell_locator.FindClosestPoint([-23.7, -48.4, -906.4], c, cellId, subId, d)
```

I added the lines:

```
reverse.Update()
```

and

```
my_cell_locator.BuildLocator()
```

Then I changed the following lines:

```
cellId = 0
subId = 0
d = 0.0
```

To...

```
cellId = vtk.reference(0)
subId = vtk.reference(0)
d = vtk.reference(0.0)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'reverse' is not defined, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For vtk version 8 had to change vtk.reference to vtk.mutable